# How to access multiple html file elements from same external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

This is what I want to know if we can access multiple html file elements from the same external javascript file.

Scenario:

**one.html**

```
<div id="one" onclick="oneDIV"></div>
```

**two.html**

```
<div id="two" onclick="twoDIV"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
function oneDIV(){
    var instance = document.getElementById("one");
}


function TwoDIV(){
    var instance = document.getElementById("two");
}
```

The question would be more specific if I ask **One JS File for Multiple Pages**

Comment: Can you expand on your question? How are the html files loaded and how is the script used

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have a single function which does something with the clicked DIV.

You can achieve this with the `this` keyword. `this` references the DOM object from which the event was triggered in this case.

For example if you want to alert the DIV's content you can do it like this:

```
<div id='one' onClick='shout()'>foo</div>
<div id='two' onClick='shout()'>bar</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function shout(){
        alert(this.innerHtml());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I didn't understand it correctly, please comment. I will edit it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What I actually meant was the way I've defined those two functions inside the external script file, is it the right way to do it, because I cannot access the div of one.html file but the div of two.html is working fine and getting accessed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try `<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
in the `<head>` tag in one.html and two.html
tell if it worked or not.